# Trying to import a specific portion of the local security policy template for account lockout

Tags: group-policy, windows-command-prompt

I am trying to implement a solution to modify the local security policy on client machines using SECEDIT and a provided inf file, however /IMPORT requires the /db parameter to be listed but I cannot find the path to the active policy. I am essentially trying to script the act of importing a template from the snap-in GUI to enforce account lockout. Any help would be appreciated, this is for Windows 10 and 11 systems. Thanks.